# Android: Importing Project, Cant run due to multiple errors?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am attempting to import code to **Eclipse** to run it. It imports correctly but then almost all of the packages and classes contain errors.

E.g:

[image]

Almost every Line either has the error:

```
" " cannot be resolved to a type
```

or

```
" " is undefined
```

I am asking as I do not know how to fix the errors. Is it just an error within my eclipse? It is not a syntax error etc as I know the code runs on another machine.

Comment: Those errors probably means that your project did *not* import correctly. Check your build path, etc.

Comment: Right click on project, Properties, Java build path, look through tabs for errors

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with BuildPath, the fix (I think) is:
Right click on the project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Go to the libraries tab
To add libraries, you need to press add library, or add jar. It's probably a jar you are missing, but I can't tell for sure. I recommend looking at the place from which you got the project and if they say what jars or libraries this project used. Then add those to your build path.